# What is the best way to check a certain input in php and proceed if it meets the required format?

Tags: php, mysql, get, strpos

I got lost in a using strpos() and ltrim()'s. Would anyone be able to help me out with my problem? I'd want the page to only accept inputs that start with "A" or "B" then is immediately followed by an integer. Like the following:

```
A1 = accepted
B1 = accepted
AB = rejected
1A = rejected
1 = rejected
B123 = accepted
```

I am using `$_GET` and the URL is somehow like `page.php?id=` The numbers actually come from an auto-increment primary key in MySQL so lengths will vary as entries are added.

Comment: You are better off doing that with a regular expression, as shown by @eugene-rieck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php > $pattern="/^[A|B]\d+$/";
php > echo preg_match($pattern,"A1",$matches); print_r($matches);
1Array
(
    [0] => A1
)
php > echo preg_match($pattern,"B1",$matches); print_r($matches);
1Array
(
    [0] => B1
)
php > echo preg_match($pattern,"1A",$matches); print_r($matches);
0Array
(
)
php >
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. I probably should give it a rest for now. Thanks, @Eugen!

Comment: @PiTheNumber I wasn't showing finished code, but a way to go. I also beg to disagree on the readability of this regex: You are right with some fancy regexes out there, but this one dosen't seem too hard to read for me.

Comment: @EugenRieck I know this is just a command line example. And yes, this one is not so hard to read, if you know about regexes. But for me it looks like OP don't know much about regexp. So for him it would be bad to use code he does not understand.

Comment: Funny thing is, I did the entire sign up form using regex for error-catching. I guess I was just tired and tried too hard to think of a solution this time around. The regex answer works for me but thanks for sharing input as well, @PiTheNumber.

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to avoid regexp. It is bad style because it is hard to read and difficult to debug. It is not so much shorter anyway:

```
preg_match("/^[A|B]\d+$/", $i, $m); if (count($m) > 0) {}
if ($i[0] == 'A' || $i[0] == 'B') && is_numeric(substr($i, 1)) {}
```

Full code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // A or B and the rest a number
    if (($id[0] == 'A' || $id[0] == 'B') && is_numeric(substr($id, 1)))
    {
        // accepted
    }
}
```

Comment: I beg to differ about the readability issue in the case given – it's not as if the regex read `(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)`. Any uncertainties are easily clarified by a small inline comment along the lines of "// Check if $i starts with A or B followed by an int". Also, if the condition ever changes, a regex is easier to fix than a huge `if ()` clause.

Comment: So you are saying `is_numeric` is harder to understand then `\d`. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? ltrim($_GET['id']) : null;
if( $id && ($id[0]=='A'||$id[0]=='B') && is_numeric(substr($id,1)) ){
    echo 'accepted';
}else{
    echo 'rejected';
}
```

Comment: Edited to fit variable length number (`substr($id,1)`)

Comment: @PiTheNumber The OP's condition reads *"… inputs that start with A or B … immediately followed by an integer"*. Thus, an input of "A1X" would be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/^([AB][0-9])/', $yourstring) > 0)
{
    // valid input
}
```

Comment: you're missing a +, that'll fail A12 (But you've been beaten to it :)) )

Comment: @AD7six OP said: "… only accept inputs that start with "A" or "B" then is immediately followed by an integer." – that is precisely what the regex checks for; no further processing intended ;)

Comment: "The numbers actually come from an auto-increment primary key in MySQL so lengths will vary as entries are added." I can quote the original post too vzwick

Comment: @AD7six Still, all he wants to check for is A|B[0-9]